# Ms Access Relationship between subform and form

Tags: database, ms-access, foreign-keys, relational-database, primary-key

I am beginner with Ms Access and databases
I am building meeting management database. I am stuck at some point please help

Database purpose is to manage meetings with different firms which are in most cases reoccurs time to time

Table that I have created.

Table 1 - Firms

```
FirmID - AutoNo - PK
FirmName - Text
....
```

Table 2 - FirmReps (to store multiple reps of each firm)

```
FirmRepID - AutoNo    
FirmID - FK    
RepName - Text
...
```

Table 3 - Meeting Details (will be the main form)

```
MeetingID - AutoNo    
MeetingDate - Date/Time    
MeetingTime - Date/time    
Venue - Text    
FirmName - FK
...
```

I am looking for solution that when I enter meeting details and select the firm name all individuals will be shown in separate sub-form where I can select (tick) the interested reps for meeting

I have created a subform for FirmReps and link the master with FirmID but Every time I select the firm name all the reps are shown and not saved/linked with the meeting ID.

Comment: Look at the NWind sample database, particularly the Orders form. Orders are equivalent to a meeting, Order Details is the same as firm reps and the reps are equivalent to Products.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning, it works as i needed, the only thing is left. i have created a subform with firmreps it shows all of the reps available instead of only reps belongs to the selected firm is the main form.

Comment: Make sure you set the link child and master fields to the meeting ID. The reps list must have a meeting ID. If you are new to MS Access, always make use of the wizards.

Comment: Everything is setup as suggested, link child & master fields are setup with meeting ID and it works. The only thing is left in subform all reps from all firms are showing instead of selected FirmName reps in combo box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get only the selected firm in the combobox on the subform, you can refer to the main form FirmID. Set the Row Source for the combo like so:

```
 SELECT FirmRepID, RepName FROM FirmReps
 WHERE  FirmID = Forms!NameOfMeetingsFormHere!FirmID
```